# Identifying line intersects within single polyline shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a shapefile representing a road network, there is an issue with the network in that some roads have duplicated features in the shapefile (seperate digitisations with seperate attributes but for the same road).

My objective is to identify these duplicates.

As the attributes are different, I can't look in there for the duplicates so I was wondering if this could be done spatially?

I can't find a tool which allows me to check intersects within one file though, only between two seperate shapefiles.

Comment: Have you tried the **Delete duplicate geometries** tool from the _Processing Toolbox_?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, yes i have tried that but unfortunately they are not all exact duplicates (I should have clarified this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using qgis, use **"Vector - Research Tools - Select by Location"** and give the same feature in both the tabs and mark  **only the third option** **(overlap/cross)** and proceed.

I think this will solve the issue.